# How to Emulate Chrome's Ctrl+F Counter

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, find

Chrome's find feature (ctrl+f) has a counter in the input box. For instance, the "1 of 40" in the following picture:

[image: Chrome find counter]

How can I emulate this placement? I can code the counter myself, but how do I actually get the numbers to appear there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search box has the following structure:

```
span
   input
   label
```

There is a `span` element with a fixed width, height, white background, border etc. Inside this is an `input` element for the search field. This is followed by a label element. Since the `input` element is an `inline-block` (by default), the label appears to the right of it.

**Simple Example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.search-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.search-bar input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.search-bar input:focus  {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="search-bar">
  <input id="search" type="text" />
  <label for="search">1 of 20</label>
</span>
```

**Update:** Added CSS to remove outline on focus of the `input` element

Comment: Make sure you cancel out the focus state on the input or it will look awful in chrome.

Comment: So it's not actually in the input, it just appears to be so?

Comment: @RohanKhajuria The search is an `input`, but the label itself is to the right of it. It looks as though it's floating on top of it, but that's just the background   blending.

Comment: I can't get it to work. My HTML code is: `<span id="searchBar"><input type="text" id="searchText" autofocus><label for="searchText">0 of 0</label></span>`. I didn't bother with how it looks, so I just added `#searchBar {
 height: 30px;
 width: 200px;
}` to my CSS. If it makes a difference, I'm using bootstrap and the html is the popup of a Chrome extension.

Comment: @RohanKhajuria The whole point is about how it looks. Take my example and go from there. Bootstrap will have some CSS rules that will change the look so you can append their selectors to the markup, and provide more specific rules to the custom selectors to get the look you are after. Right now your question is somewhat ambiguous, hence why others voted it on-hold.